# Can i mix two primary key from two different tables into one Primary key in a new table

Tags: sql, database, database-design

First, I have 4 tables, Cat, Dog, Appointment, and User Table. I separated the dog and cat table because if a User registers a pet, it will create new data with his/her UserID as a fore key. In my appointment table, I set the Appointment ID as the primary key, and I'm planning(if possible) to make a fore key named PetID where either CatID(primary key of Cat table) and DogID(primary key of Dog Table) will be inserted into the PetID which corresponds to which pet the User registered.

Comment: You should not have separated cats and dogs into separate tables.  You should just have a pet table, with a pet type.  After all, unless you are a veterinarian, cats and dogs are pretty similar, at least from the data modeling pespective.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff I can do this but, can I seprate the ID into two? Because i will need to retrieve data in the future where for example, which Dogs had a record of this type of treatment. I am thinking of querying this with DogIDs and CatIDs to separate them when a data reteiving is needed.

Comment: . . You would just filter on `pet_type`.

Answer (score 0):

No, this will create a confliction when you will add the join to the **Cat** or **Dog** table with the **Appointment** table.

The recommended way is to add two fore keys with **CatPetID** and **DogPetID** so that when you want to retrieve the appointments data for cats or dogs it will give you correct data.

Comment: With this way, I will need to put null when the for DogID when i'm appointing for my Cat right? Won't this give a problem when retrieving data?

Comment: As Gordon pointed out, you should have `PetID` and `PetType` rather than `DogPetID` and `CatPetID`.